# Fixing partial URL's in Rails for a URL shortener

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url-rewriting, url-shortener

I'm making a URL shortener following the instructions [here](https://sethvargo.com/create-a-custom-domain-url-shortener-with-rails/).

However one of the disadvantages/corner cases not covered by this tutorial is that for the redirect "go" method defined in the code as below to work:

```
def go
    @link = Link.find_by_in_url!(params[:in_url])
    redirect_to @link.out_url, :status => @link.http_status
end
```

a full url is required. So for example while https://www.google.com/ will work as an input url, www.google.com or google.com will result in [BASEURL]/google.com or [BASEURL]/www.google.com for the redirect.

I'm guessing that I either need to use Regex in my model code to detect http or www missing parameters, or edit redirect_to. Can anyone point me towards a way to allow url's that lack http or www parameters to be used as input url's for a url shortener?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of the `redirect_to` method (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html), if you pass a string parameter that doesn't contain any protocol, it will redirect to the url constructed by appending the given string to the current protocol and host.

So the best way to do that is to use a `before_validation` call in the `Link` model that will add the protocol to the `out_url` attribute :

```
before_validation :add_protocol_to_out_url

def add_protocol_to_out_url
  unless self.out_url.blank?
    self.out_url.slice!(/http:\/\/|https:\/\//)
    self.out_url = "http://#{self.out_url}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The given answers may be correct in most cases, but I wouldn't depend on a custom regex written by yourself to handle all cases.  Use the [URI](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/URI.html) module to parse the given String, and then use its methods to get what you need:

```
require 'uri'

def normalize_url(in_url)
    uri = URI.parse(in_url)
    if uri.scheme.nil?
      uri.scheme = "http"
    end
    if uri.host.nil?
      uri.host = uri.path
      uri.path = ""
    end
    uri.to_s
end
```

You may need to add additional cases to handle 'www' missing.

Answer (score -1):

Check the full `URL shortener` implementation in rails 5 here [Rails URL shortener](https://github.com/vijaymali7/url-shorten)